# How can I append data in powershell to a different file depending on what month the data came from?

Tags: powershell, date, append, office365api

I am pulling data on adoption of  Office 365 products on a daily basis. I don't know how to convert my current logic to write to a new file based on file size to one based on the report date.

My original thought process was to use an if statement to split the data out by month and have 12 files already ready to append to (depending on the month of data) but this seems inefficient.

```bsh
$name = "O365SPSiteActivity.csv"
$auth=Get-AuthCode
$accesstoken=$auth[1]

### data pulling process has been omitted ###

if ($report -ne $null)
{
    ###New section for making the new files
    #Get current file
    $source = "D:\O365Data\"+ $name 
    $File = Get-Item $source

    If (((Get-Item $file).Length/1MB) -ge 700) 
    {
        $date = (get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)
        $RenamedFileName = "O365SPSiteActivity-$date.csv"
        Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $RenamedFileName
        $FileName = "D:\temp\" + $name
        Send-MailMessage –From svc_sps10@kbslp.com –To shelby.cundiff@kbslp.com –Subject “New File Has been Created" –Body “New File Name: $RenamedFileName "  -SmtpServer kbslp-com.mail.protection.outlook.com -Port 25


    }
    Else
    {
        $FileName = "D:\temp\" + $name
        Copy $File $FileName
    }


    #########################################################################
    $Data=@()
    $c=1
    foreach ($row in $report)
    {   Write-Progress -Activity $row.'User Principal Name' -PercentComplete (($c/$report.count)*100) -ID 4
        $string = "" | Select "???Report Refresh Date","User Principal Name","Is Deleted","Deleted Date","Last Activity Date","Viewed or Edited File Count",
                "Synced File Count","Shared Internally File Count","Shared Externally File Count","Visited Page Count","Report Period"
        $string.'???Report Refresh Date' = Get-Date($row.'ï»¿Report Refresh Date') -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        $string.'User Principal Name' = $row.'User Principal Name'
        $string.'Is Deleted' = $row.'Is Deleted'
        $string.'Deleted Date' = $row.'Deleted Date'
        $string.'Last Activity Date' = $row.'Last Activity Date'
        $string.'Viewed or Edited File Count' = $row.'Viewed or Edited File Count'
        $string.'Synced File Count' = $row.'Synced File Count'
        $string.'Shared Internally File Count' = $row.'Shared Internally File Count'
        $string.'Shared Externally File Count' = $row.'Shared Externally File Count'
        $string.'Visited Page Count' = $row.'Visited Page Count'
        $string.'Report Period' = $row.'Report Period'
        $Data += $string
        $c++
    }
    $Data | Export-Csv -Append -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Force
    #$FolderUrl = $teamSitePath + "/" + $ListName
    #$UploadFileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($FileName)
    #Upload-SPOFile -WebUrl $teamSiteUrl -spCredentials $SPOCreds -FolderUrl $FolderUrl -FileInfo $UploadFileInfo
    $newFile = Get-Item $FileName
    Copy $newFile $File.FullName
}
$report = $null
$Data = $null
```

Ideally, i'd like to change this script to write to a file like:

O365SPSiteActivity-2019-Oct.csv during October, then O365SPSiteActivity-2019-Nov.csv during November, etc. depending on when the data is from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the current date, or the date from the spreadsheet?

```
$date = (get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)
```

will output to O365SPSiteActivity-2019-Oct.csv if you run it today.

If you're looking to chunk up the CSV based on dates within the data, I might move the export-CSV inside the foreach loop, and modify it to use a name similar to above instead of appending it to the $Data array.

```
$Data = "2019-May-31"
Get-Date -Format yyyy-MMM -Date ([datetime]::parseexact($Data, 'yyyy-MMM-dd', $null))
$FileName = "O365SPSiteActivity-$date.csv"
$Data | Export-Csv -Append -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

That'll write each line to the appropriate CSV file- you'll end up with a different CSV file for every months worth of data.

Note that the 'yyyy-MMM-dd' in parseexact will need to match the format of the date that you're feeding it. For example, if you're sorting it based on $row.'Report Period' that has the date as 12/31/19, it would be 'MM/dd/yy' instead (notice I changed from - to / as the separator). Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#dSpecifier) listing what each letter in that means.

Comment: Thanks- I am looking to use the date from the data, so I think your suggestion of a for each loop might be best.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you write to a temporary file first and copy if over a (possibly existing) file when done?
If I understand the question, you would like to create a new report csv each month.
Then, why not simply do something like this:

```
# create a filename for this month
$currentReport = 'O365SPSiteActivity-{0:yyyy-MMM}.csv' -f (Get-Date)
```

and export `-Append` your data into that? If the file does not already exist, it will be created, otherwise the new data will be appended to it.

Comment: Right now we right to a temporary file because usually the file writing process is where the script fails (if it is going to fail). I think by combining your naming scheme and the other idea of a for each loop to determine what month the data is from, I can get what I need. Thanks!